java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A null comparator has been passed to RowSorter using <display:table> in JSP
I have some code like this:
<sql:query var="task_work">
Select * from tasks
</sql:query>
<display:table name="${task_work.rows }" sort="list" id="small_jobs" export="false" class="tableoutput" defaultsort="1" defaultorder="ascending">

<!-- Here, I want to use a `c:when` or `c:if` tag to ask for permission, if it's `false`, then 
don't show columns, if `true` then show -->

<c:choose>
<c:when test="<%=AskForPermission( ((TreeMap<?,?>)pageContext.getAttribute("small_jobs")).get("permission").toString() )%>">
<display:column title="End">${small_jobs.name}</display:column>
<display:column title="End">${small_jobs.description}</display:column>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
</display:table>

But I get this error:

Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/guh] threw
exception [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A null comparator has
been passed to RowSorter. A comparator instance is required] with root
cause java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A null comparator has been
passed to RowSorter. A comparator instance is required

I tried <c:if> tag, and <c:when> tag, outside and inside <display:table>.

Yes its a typo but thanks

@JorgeCampos Has nothing to do with EL, and whitespace is ignored while it's parsed.
